# what if m = infinity in y = mx+c?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm having trouble trying to understand linear functions.

First, we recognize a function from a graph using vertical straight line, if it crosses two points, we say the graph does not represent a function.

if we use the vertical line method on y = mx + c if m equals or approaches to infinity, then y = mx + c does not represents a function, let alone represent a linear function.

Am i right or wrong in this situation ?

Comment: Yes, a vertical line $x=c$ is not a function. It fails vertical line test, intersecting it at infinitely many points. In the definition of linear function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, such that $f(x)=mx+c$, $\; m$ and $c$ are real constants. Therefore an undefined value of $m$, as you know infinity does not belong to $\Bbb R$, can make $f$ undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula to represent a line in 2D space is: $Ax+By+C=0, A\in R, B\in R$($A$ and $B$ should not equal to $0$ simultaneously), and $y=mx+c$ is a restricted form that excludes the case $B=0$.

So, w.r.t your question, a vertical line is exactly the case that $B=0$, and $Ax+C=0, A\neq 0$ is a function of $y$, namely $x(y)=0$, which means that given any $y$, $x$ remains the same number $-\frac{C}{A}$. It can be understood in the same way with $y=c$.

And, when you let $m\to\infty$, you reach the limitation of the representation ability of this restricted form $y=mx+c$.

Answer (score -1):

Well.. as the 'm' represents the slope of the line which is given by tan (angle of the line with the x-axis), so if the 'm' i.e. slope is equal to infinity therefore the tan of the angle will be infinity and since tan of 90 degree is infinity(actually its undefined but it approaches infinity at pi/2 radians so we can assume), thus your line will be perpendicular to the x axis.. for e.g. x = 5 can be such a line.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).